# Attribute meta-data#com.google.android.geo.API_KEY@value at AndroidManifest.xml requires a placeholder substitution but no value for <maps key>

Tags: android, android-studio, android-manifest

**Android Manifest File**
The error in google api key i also attach the screeenshot of the error[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uYZQl.png)

```
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="{maps key*****}" />

</application>
```